# Change post thumbnail size on wordpress page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I made a separate wordpress page to display all of my featured images and they do display but I need help on how to make them display to their actual size not as really small images.

```
 <?php
$the_query = new WP_Query();
$the_query->query("cat=4&nopaging=true");

if ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

  if(has_post_thumbnail()) : 
    the_post_thumbnail();
  endif;

endwhile; 
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata();
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
?>

<img src='<?php echo $image[0]; ?>' />
```

That is my code right now the page is http://rickwarren.veracitycolab.com/banners/

Thanks!

This is what my new code looks like and the images are still the same any thoughts?

```
 <?php
$the_query = new WP_Query();
$the_query->query("cat=4&nopaging=true");
if ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

  if(has_post_thumbnail()) : 
    the_post_thumbnail();
  endif;

endwhile; 
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata();
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it still hasn't changed after you've added the 'full' parameter you might want to try 
the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Usually it helps for me when I've been messing around with custom thumbnail sizes.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of [wp_get_attachment_image_src()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) is the size of the image to return. Using `full` here should give you the full size image.

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
```

**EDIT:** Of course this part of your code isn't doing anything since it's outside the loop.

Change line 8 to `the_post_thumbnail('full');`

You can delete everything after the line that begins with `$image...`. [Codex page here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

Comment: I just added the changes and still no luck, any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `wp_get_attachment_image_src(...)` a size parameter as well. In your case, you want 'full', so `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post->ID, 'full' )`. From [the Codex for that function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src):

> $size
>       (string/array) (optional) Size of the image shown for an image attachment: either a string keyword (thumbnail, medium, large or full)
>   or a 2-item array representing width and height in pixels, e.g.
>   array(32,32). As of Version 2.5, this parameter does not affect the
>   size of media icons, which are always shown at their original size.
>
> ```
>     Default: thumbnail
> ```

CSS rules could still 'shrink' the image though, so if it doesn't work check the URL in the HTML source to confirm that the correct image is being requested, then check the stylesheet.

Comment: I checked the stylesheet and inserted the changes (played around with the different sizes and code) and still no luck. Any more ideas or things I should check?

Comment: Did you check to make sure the 'full' size image is correct? That is, did you "check the URL in the HTML source to confirm that the correct image is being requested"?